# Clear a delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, delegates

What is the correct way to clear a UIWebView delegate ?

In my dealloc function, I added

```
[myWebView setDelegate:nil];
[myWebView release];
```

And is the first ligne necessary ?

EDIT : and what if my object was not a UIWebView but a `NSFetchedResultsController` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the delegate to nil is one thing. Other, quite as important or even more, is how to cleanly shut down a loading UIWebView in a case when you don't care about the result anymore and you're about to release a view containing your UIWebView.

Here is a really good answer to above questions and more: [How to safely shut down a loading UIWebView in viewWillDisappear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789984/how-to-safely-shut-down-a-loading-uiwebview-in-viewwilldisappear/827337#827337). It'll give a good overview on UIWebView's life-cycle.

A hint on calling `stopLoading`: you don't have to check if anything is being loaded with `isLoading` before calling `stopLoading` - just call `stopLoading` directly and it will do nothing if nothing is being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the code above.  No, you probably don't need to clear the delegate.

But, if you have ClassA and ClassB, and you've set ClassA to be the delegate of ClassB, then what you need to be careful with is ... when ClassA is deallocated while ClassB is still in use.

So, to handle that, ClassA would clear (itself) from the delegate property of ClassB in the `dealloc` method for ClassA.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need only to cancel all request before release it by:

```
[webView stopLoading];
```

Cheers!.