# Sound still running after releasing UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiwebview

I have pushed a `UIWebView` in `UINavigationController` . This webview will play sound .
During playing the sound I receive a phone call so I pop the `UIWebView` from the `UINavigationController` and and also i do this

```
myWebView.delegate = nil ;
[myWebView release];
myWebView = nil ;
```

and also I do this

```
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
[[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeCachedResponseForRequest:tempAdPlayer.request];
[myWebView loadRequest:nil];
```

the problem is when I return from call I find the sound still running .
Does anyone have a solution ?

by the way I have put some code in

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView1
```

and this function is still running after releasing the webview

Comment: Check this link. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789984/how-to-safely-shut-down-a-loading-uiwebview-in-viewwilldisappear

Hope it helps.Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myWebView.delegate = nil ;
[myWebView release];
myWebView = nil ;
```

Also, load the web view again to blank url, where you want to stop the sound then stopped.

```
[myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"about:blank"]]];
```

Comment: I Have tried this solution before you wrote it :D and I have succeeded .